# Is the past tense “rose” correct here?

Tags: grammar

In the following extract from a CNBC article, the author uses the expression “economists expect that prices….rose”. The usage of the past tense sounds a bit queer to me. I think “should rise ” or “will rise” would be more appropriate.

> Economists expect that prices across a broad spectrum of goods and services rose 0.4% on the month, just ahead of the January pace of 0.3%, according to the Dow Jones consensus.

The sense the author wants to convey is clear, but  my question is:

Is the use of past tense grammatically correct in the above context? .

Comment: If the February figures were not available at the time of writing, I would expect "...that prices will have risen...".

Comment: The use of the past tense in that context is common in economic reporting. They are reporting a prediction about a recent event: The sentence refers to a specific time period, "on the month." By the time the report is published, that month is already over. So, the economists are essentially reporting on what they believe already happened.

Comment: @Style - so we could say it is financial jargon?

Comment: @Mr.Black Yes, it's quite common although it doesn't sound grammatically correct.

Comment: Not just financial jargon. It would be common in any situation where something has definitely already happened (i.e. the event id definitely in the past) but we won't know exactly what happened until a time in the future. If I had a bg with 20 red balls and one green ball, you pick one without showing it to me. I would say "I expect you picked a red ball".

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is confusing because of the combination of "expect", which refers to something happening in the future, and "rose", which is past tense.

I think what they're trying to say -- without looking it up to get the full quote -- is that the rise or fall is in the past, but economists don't have all the statistics in yet to know just what happened. So what I think the writer means is, "Economists expect that when the numbers come in, they will show that prices rose." They expect something to happen in the future: statistics to be available. But the statistics will be about something in the past.

You wouldn't say "they expect that prices will rise" because the rising or falling under discussion is in the past. You can't drop the "expect" and just say "prices rose" because they don't know that for sure yet.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Maybe someone thinks *"...that prices will have risen..."* is the ***only*** "acceptable / correct" verb form for the context. But if that is the case, I think they're *seriously* mistaken.

Comment: ...you certainly [won't often encounter](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expect+you+went%2Cexpect+you+will+have+gone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) *I expect you will have gone [somewhere]* instead of *I expect you **went** there*.

Comment: @Jay - the meaning is quite clear to me, the issue is grammar. As it stands, is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: @Mr.Black Actually, it *is* about meaning, and not grammar. There's nothing *grammatically* wrong with "I look forward to you woke up"; it has a subject and a verb and uses the past tense. The only problem is that the verb phrase "look forward to" has a *meaning* that has to do with the future, and doesn't make sense in the sentence. Meanwhile this answer and some comments show this could be a rarer but valid meaning.

Comment: @Mr.Black Also note https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expect meaning 3: sometimes "I expect" can be used like "I suppose" or "I suspect," as in "I expect that new mayor is a crook, just like the last one." (I feel like this usage is slightly archaic?) In this sense it's shorthand for "I expect future events to confirm my initial assessment." It could maybe even be used thus for the past: "That Henry VIII! I expect he would have stopped at one wife if he'd known how much trouble the next five would be."

Comment: @Mr.Black But don't worry too much about that kind of usage; it doesn't feel idiomatic in modern usage; maybe outdated or highly regional; it feels appropriate for colorful colloquial dialogue maybe in a 19th-century work.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I don’t agree. Here, as clearly stated  we have an expectation that depends on past events. There must be a correct grammar combination of verbs to express this concept. And I don’t think it is the one in the extract. This is ELL so you are “teaching” something to learners

Comment: @Mr.Black Well, maybe I'm making too fine a point for now by distinguishing between "meaning" and "grammar." In any case, what we're talking about is "whether these words and ideas work together," and the only problem is that you expect (hehe) the word "expect" to mean only "anticipate, in the future." Note that the MW definition I linked above (#3, "suppose, think") shows there can be other meanings.

Comment: @Mr.Black (Plus, the fact that as this answer and other comments show, there's still an "in the future" meaning at work here, if the usage is shorthand for "They expect *that future analysis of the data will show that* prices rose (in the past)."